# Azure AD Tenant deletion prevented by licensed-based subscriptions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Despite intensive research over many months I cannot delete my AzureAD tenant. The tenant deletion wizard informs me that I must use Store for Business to remove seat-based subscriptions. Problem is there are no visible seat-based subscriptions showing in the Store for Business. Does anyone know how I can identify the seat-based subscriptions that are preventing me from deleting my Azure AD tenant?

Two pictures to aid understanding are below…

[Azure AD tenant deletion wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYgR2.jpg)

[Store for Business Products and Services Subscriptions tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5txHY.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find the hidden subscriptions in the admin center under **"Billing >> Your Products"**, first cancel the subscription, refresh and delete, wait 24h and it'll be deleted, then go to Azure Portal and delete the tenant.

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/89041/delete-azure-account-tenant.html

Please reach out to [support](https://ms.portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_Azure_Support/HelpAndSupportBlade/overview) if above solution is not working they will try to delete it manually (~3 day period after deletion for it to update on your Tenant).

Please refer this [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/89041/delete-azure-account-tenant.html) had discussed the same.

Comment: thank you @RahulKumarShaw-MT.  i check M365 Admin but the only subs I could see were my old Visual Studio M365 E5 subs that had been deleted already.  As you suggest it is best I contact support so they can help delete this tenant.  Many thanks for supplyimg the relevamt info